# lift starts at floor 1 and goes up to floor 6. find number ways in which people can leave lift

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A lift can record how many people leave lift at each floor. It starts at floor 1 and goes up to floor 6.
(A) How many different records are possible of people leaving the lift?
(B) what if 8 people consist of 5 men and 3 women and lift can distinguish a man from a woman?

I tried solving part A by doing $C^{n+5-1}_{5-1}$ where $n$ is total number of people in lift

And for part B, I was unable to do anything

Comment: Do you know the method of stars and bars? This is probably the way I would approach this.

Comment: Do people also add up in the floors $2,3,4,5$? Or they only get on the lift in floor $1$?

Comment: Your answer for the first question is correct.  For the second question, treat the men and women separately.

Comment: You have two sets of fruits say A and B how would you distribute them in say n baskets ? Got it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ people each have $5$ different options to decide which floor to leave the lift, and each person's decision on which floor to leave is independent, we get the answer to [A] as $5^n$.

Comment: That approach assumes that person A leaving on floor 2 and person B leaving on floor 3 is different from person B leaving on floor 2 and person A leaving on floor 3 i.e. it assumes that people in the lift are distinguishable.

Comment: Which is true, right? People are usually considered distinguishable.